# Windows 7 very slow after restart, but fine after complete shutdown?

Tags: windows-7

I have a Dell pc running Windows 7 with the Intel i3 processor.

Whenever I restart the computer, the os crawls. For example, I move the mouse and then I see it move on the screen 10 seconds later... Everything runs slowly.  This happens *only* on a restart (it's fine when I turn it on after it has been shut down).

Any ideas what is causing this (I haven't installed any new software since buying it).  Does it sound like a hardware or software issue?

Answer (score 1):

do you have any external devices connected to the computer?

some devices don't reset themselves properly if there is a reboot.

I have a related issue with an external hard disk, if it is connected to during a reboot, I get poor performance or sometimes I can see it at all. But a shutdown and restart is fine.

So, I suggest disconnecting any peripherals and trying a reboot to see if that helps.